# no http server will serve pages from my server

Tags: apache, http, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I have ubuntu 14.04 server edition with nodejs, mongodb and nginx installed. This worked fine until yesterday. My internet went down for about 8 hours because of a storm and upon coming back up, nodejs works, mongo works, but anyone connecting to port 80 gets `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. i attempted to switch the listening port just to see what would happen and got the same result. I can use the server's internal IP and i still get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, however visiting port 80 via lynx on the server itself via localhost or 127.0.0.1, the application works just fine. I have also tried this using apache instead of nginx and it does not work either. ive disabled my ufw completely, restarted the server, double and triple checked configurations. even netstat says the server is listening on port 80, an nmap scan shows port 80 open and listening, but trying to connect to it gives `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I do not know what to do and based on google and stack overflow search results, im the first person in the history of web servers to ever have to ask this question, so alas i could find nothing helpful anywhere.

Thanks in advance

UFW Status

```
user@io# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Nginx Status

```
user@io# service nginx status
* nginx is running
```

Nginx Access Log

```
user@io:/var/log/nginx# cat access.log 
::1 - - [26/Feb/2016:16:04:23 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 7746 "-" "Lynx/2.8.8pre.4 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1 GNUTLS/2.12.23"
```

netstat

```
user@io# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      977/mongod      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23009/nginx     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:28017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      977/mongod      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      974/sshd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9561            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2083/node       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      23009/nginx     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      974/sshd        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27712           0.0.0.0:*                           808/dhclient    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           808/dhclient    
udp6       0      0 :::52391                :::*                                808/dhclient    `
```

Comment: Not sure of your setup but does the problem lie somewhere else? Have you  got a router / firewall with port forwarding? Is your IP address static (no chance it was renewed once the internet come back online)? Bit of a broad question.

Comment: IP address is static and there is a firewall in front of it, but i ruled that out by setting the static IP to a 1:1 NAT to bypass the firewall completely (All ports are forwarded no restrictions) plus if it were the external firewall then i should be able to access the application via its internal IP. but yes that was the first thing i thought as well when it became obvious that things seemed ot be working properly on server

Comment: I hate these kinds of problems, too many variables and probably turns out to be a simple solution... after hours of messing around. How many network interfaces do you have?

Comment: well to add to the oddities, if i cange the nginx port to 3000 then port 3000 says `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` but port 80 WORKS! nothign should be on port 80 if nginx is listening to port 3000

Comment: actually it works fine on port 80 if it tell it to listen on any port other than 80. this makes no sense! same with apache!

Comment: oh and i have 2 interfaces but only one is being used

Comment: Must be firewall?? Have you tried resetting iptables just to test?

Comment: Also, try http://0.0.0.0:80

Comment: I actually hadn't tried resetting iptables, but i just have and the issue seems to remain :( also 0.0.0.0:80 gives me nothign from localhost

Comment: So with firewall off, iptables cleared and apache/nginx listening to port 80... `wget http://0.0.0.0:80` returns nothing?

Comment: `Connecting to 0.0.0.0:80... failed: Connection refused.` is what returns

Comment: Whats the output of sudo `iptables -t nat -nvL`? Maybe a NAT rule

Comment: `Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 359 packets, 59391 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   78  4672 REDIRECT   tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 3000`

Comment: so its redirecting to port 3000??

Comment: it would appear so except there are no iptables rules in effect so there is absolutely no reason that it should do this

Comment: this is th e result of `iptables -S`
`-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `iptables -t nat -F` to clear all pre-routing rules.

Comment: this did it. i have no idea how that got there in the first place as no one ever added it, nor was 3000 used prior to me changing the port in nginx to that port at random today, but this did solve the issue thanks

Comment: Bingo... Try restarting the server to make sure there are no scripts adding nat rules to iptables automatically. If it doesn't work after a restart then you need to go on a hunt to find the offending script.

Comment: Said Firewall after 3 comments... an hour ago